# Local function visibility change between R2015 and R2016?

Tags: matlab, visibility, scoping

I'm running into a strange problem w/ MATLAB code which runs fine in R2012 and R2015, but not in R2016.

Here's the relevant (I think)  snippets.  The command string in the variable `commmandstring` refers to a subfunction in a company-private toolset, with its own defined class. That is, there are a bunch of functions which are called with the syntax `cfunc.func1(...) ,  cfunc.func2(...)` and so on. 
The body of the function has already established that `cfunc` is a parent function of this class.  I can call `cfunc.getdatabycycle(cycle,cycle,288,17,17)` directly from the command line and it'll run fine.  But inside a function with the following snippets,

```
 >> commandstring commandstring = getdatabycycle(cycle,cycle,10,5,3) 
 % char string

>> ghandle = @(cycle,enc) eval(sprintf('cfunc.%s',commandstring));

>> [stat,data] = feval(ghandle, cycle,enc);
```

the In MATLAB 2016, the call to 'feval'  fails with an error message:

```
K>> [stat,data] = feval(ghandle, cycle,enc);
Undefined variable "cfunc" or class "cfunc.getdatabycycle".

Error in
myfunc  >@(cycle,enc)eval(sprintf('cfunc.%s',commandstring))
(line 90)
ghandle = @(cycle,enc) eval(sprintf('cfunc.%s',commandstring));
```

I'm wondering if this is related to some Version Change Notes from Mathworks, which discusses some sort of change to local function scope and visibility.   Any thoughts?

## EDIT:

I am asking my local "beta testers" to try using the following lines instead, as they work fine in R2015

```
gstr = sprintf('cfunc.%s',commandstring);

[stat,data] = eval(gstr) % 'cycle' is a local variable
```

#### Functionality being removed or changed

#### Visibility of local functions

> Store the function handle to the local function in a variable and use
>   that instead of the call to the local function. For example, assign
>   fcn = @myLocalFcn and update the script to use the variable fcn
>   instead of calling myLocalFcn directly.

Comment: What if you do something like `cfunc.('getdatabycycle')(cycle,cycle,288,17,17)`?

Comment: I do not think it is related. That functionality should still run fine. It may change in a future release though.

Comment: Is `cfunc` an instance of your class or is it the class name itself? If so, it looks like when you're trying to run it on 2016 you have the keyboard prompt (`K>>`) indicating that you aren't within the base workspace where `cfunc` was defined. Try running `dbquit all` to get back to the base workspace and try running your command again.

Comment: @Suever  I started out not in debug mode, and my try/catch identified a failure in this region.  If I execute  `cfunc.getdatabycycle` in debug mode, it runs fine.

Comment: `cfunc` is an instance of the class , @Suever .